# I can't find the wrong spot

Tags: python, flask, insert

I want to insert data into the database. But I got a problem that the browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

KeyError at 'parcel_idi'

1.from.html

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('insert') }}" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="parcel_idi">ID</lable>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="parcel-idi"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="parcel_name">Name</lable>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="parcel_name"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="unit">Unit</lable>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="unit"></input>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="pull-left btn btn-success">ADD +</button>
                </form>
```

2.app.py

```html
@app.route("/insert",methods=['POST'])
def insert():
    if request.method=='POST':
        parcel_idi=request.form['parcel_idi']
        parcel_name=request.form['parcel_name']
        unit=request.fomr['unit']
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            sql="INSERT INTO `parcel_table` (`parcel_idi`, `parcel_name`, `unit`) VALUES ('%s', %s', '%s')"
            cursor.execute(sql(parcel_idi,parcel_name,unit))
            conn.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('parcel1'))
```

Happens when I go to submit the form, can view the form no problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the name field in text box **"parcel-idi" to "parcel_idi"**.

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="parcel-idi"></input>
```

to

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="parcel_idi"></input>
```

Comment: oh, How did I miss this point? thank you.

Comment: Ha Ha, We miss small things and expect something big was causing the issue.